# How to send request to https webservice in Android?

Tags: php, android, web-services, https

I am trying to send a request to `Https webservice` but it always returns `404 Not Found`(**Request url not found on this server**) but it works perfectly in browser.It returns response in `XML` format. Please help guys.

Here is my code

```
    try {

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 443));

        HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();

        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(param,
                schemeRegistry);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, param);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Global.CARD_API_URL);

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "xxx"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "xxxxxxxx"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardNumber",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("expiryDate", "0515"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cvc", "123"));


        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.d("Card Details", res);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: What does your server log show?

Comment: @CommonsWare see [this](http://pastie.org/7754343)

Comment: What does **your server log** show?

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't handle the server part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've solved the question. I need to use Simple HTTP Url Connection instead of above method.

Here is the code

```
      try {
            url = new URL(api_url);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection http_connection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            http_connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
            http_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http_connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

            http_connection.setDoOutput(true);
            http_connection
                    .setFixedLengthStreamingMode(post_data.getBytes().length);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    http_connection.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(post_data);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            // Read the response.
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                    http_connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            sb = new StringBuffer();

            // Write the message response to a String.
            while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(response);
            }

               Log.d("Card Details", sb.toString());
            }catch(Exception e){

                     e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may help you out...

```
SSLContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] {
                      new X509TrustManager() {
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[]{}; }
                      }
                    }, null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```